# Dim and set the variable in 2 lines in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have this line:

```
Dim strings_extreme = input.Split(","c).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(s) s)
```

i need to Dim it in one line, and set it a value on another line

how do i do that?

would it just be `Dim strings_extreme()` ??

and then `strings_extreme = input.split....` ?

Comment: out of curiosity is it better to do it on one line or 2? or does it not matter?

Comment: The compiler will do the same thing regardless. it doesn't matter in that sense.  It does make it smaller on one line.  Sometimes, its even easier to read.  There are time where I use each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though VB.net allows you not to specify the type, it's always more safe to specify it explicitly. Hence:

```
Dim strings_extreme as string()
strings_extreme = input...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
Dim strings_extreme
strings_extreme = input.Split(","c).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(s) s)
```

One note, though.  I would turn on option strict.  Its never a good idea to declare a variable without a type.

```
Dim strings_extreme As String()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close. Here it is:

```
Dim strings as string = "grape,apples,lime"
Dim strings_extreme
strings_extreme = Input.Split(strings,",").Distinct().OrderBy(Function(s) s)
for each e in strings_extreme
    e.tostring 'do something with this
next
```